# Error message in pyomo in dynamic variable definition

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error, pyomo

I am attempting to replicate the brachistochrone optimization from [this article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwjStp6HqJnmAhUEyoUKHeevCxYQFjABegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fzenodo.org%2Frecord%2F1235943%2Ffiles%2Farticle.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1VO9FN35CjWFc1jCHPn0vk) using pyomo. Unfortunately, I recive an error message due to invalid syntax. The piece of code is as follows:

```
def f_x_definition_FLIGHT(model, i):
    return m.f_x_FLIGHT[i] == math.sqrt(2*g*m.y[i])*math.cos(m.angle[i])
m.f_x_FLIGHT = Constraint(m.N_notinitial rule = f_x_definition_FLIGHT)
```

The invalid syntax appears in the third line, in  m.f_x_FLIGHT =...

I have also constructed the Y-axis dynamic variable as

```
def f_y_definition_FLIGHT(model, i):
    return m.f_y_FLIGHT[i] == math.sqrt(2*g*m.y[i])*math.sin(m.angle[i])
m.f_y_FLIGHT = Constraint(m.N_notinitial rule = f_y_definition_FLIGHT)
```

And there is no issue there.

The dynamic functions are built as

```
m.f_x_FLIGHT             = Var(m.N_notinitial, domain = Reals) 
m.f_y_FLIGHT             = Var(m.N_notinitial, domain = Reals)
```

So I am unable to find the reason why there is a syntax error there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was the lack of a comma behind m.N_notinitial; the code works fine if written as`m.f_x_FLIGHT = Constraint(m.N_notinitial, rule = f_x_definition_FLIGHT)`